# Struts setter method wrong argument passing

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts, ognl

I have a situation where in Struts 2 application I have select tag and some values inside it

```jsp
<select name='locale'>
      <option value = "DATA1">FR_DATA1</option>
      <option value = "DATA2">FR_DATA2</option>
      <option value = "DATA3">FR_DATA3</option>
      <option value = "DATA4">FR_DATA4</option>
      <option value = "DATA5">FR_DATA5</option>
 </select>
```

now problem is that when I submit the form the value passed to setter method of the action form is label value rather than option's value like instead of `DATA1`, passing value is `FR_DATA1`.

Because a setter method is calling fine, only the argument is going unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

Use Struts tag instead of HTML

```
<s:select name="locale" list="#{'DATA1':'FR_DATA1','DATA2':'FR_DATA2','DATA3':'FR_DATA3','DATA4':'FR_DATA4','DATA5':'FR_DATA5'}"/>
```